# Can't seem to pass SESSION variables of POST

Tags: php, session

Sorry if this is a duplicate, but I really cant find anything that could solve my problem. I can pass numbers and strings like $_SESSION['blabla']="123'; but I can't pass this $_POST value from the textfield and submit button.

**Page 1 (sessions.php)**

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

!doctype stuff here

```
<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post"  action="sessions2.php">
  <label>
    <input type="text" name="damn" id="damn" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />

  </label>
</form>

<?php

$omg = $_POST['damn'];

$_SESSION['damn'] = $omg;
echo $_SESSION['damn'] ;


?>
```

**Page 2 (sessions2.php)**

```
<?php
session_start();
$fires = $_SESSION['damn'];
echo "wth";
echo $_SESSION['damn'];
?>
```

PS. Sorry for the names.. I'm truly stumped.

Comment: since your form goes to `session2.php` your `$_POST['damn']`/`$_SESSION['damn']` is never set on `sessions.php`. Add the code to `sessions2.php`

Comment: er.. what code am I to add? sorry I'm really new to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **sessions2.php**

```
// you POST "damn" variable via form, using post method, so:
$fires = $_POST['damn'];
// and:
$_SESSION['damn'] = $fier;
// or 
$_SESSION['damn'] = $_POST['damn'];
```

PHP code in file sessions.php doesn't work, because in form action you have session2.php.

Comment: thanks.. this worked! But this is using the POST method isn't it? As you said PHP code in the first file doesn't work.. then how would one go about giving a value to SESSIONS?

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the code that reads from `$_POST` in the file that you submit the form to.

Currently your process is:

1. Get request for `sessions.php`
2. Send form to browser
3. Assign `$_POST['damn']` (which is undefined) to the session.
4. User submits form
5. Get request for `sessions2.php`
6. Ignore `$_POST` (which is now populated)
7. Read from the session (where the variable is still undefined).

`damn` is populated in the form submission request (step 4/5) not the request where you are trying to read it (step 1).

Comment: so.. the SESSION['damn'] should only get values in the second page then, after reading from the POST? Therefore SESSIONS variable in the first page is not necessary? Is this correct?